# Django template convert to string

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to convert a number to a string in django's template? Or do I need to make a custom template tag. Something like:

```
{{ 1|stringify }} # '1'
```

Comment: What would the difference be between an integer and a string in a template? The template is just text, everything is a string.

Comment: No, doing something like `{% if item.type == content_type %}` one would produce a true result the other would not.

Comment: @David542: You could use `{% if item.type == content_type|add:0 %}` to accomplish some kind of type casting.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use [`stringformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) to convert a variable to a string:

```
{{ value|stringformat:"i" }}
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) for formatting options (the leading `%` should not be included).

Comment: You can indeed do that, but as I note in the comment, why would you? The output of `{{ value|stringformat:"i" }}` is exactly the same as the output of `{{ value }}`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: when writing an if statement the type does matter - so it may be needed to convert the type in the template and use that value in a comparison later.

Comment: Adding to this you cannot do something like `{% with var="this is an integer: "|add:an_int_variable %}` without `|stringformat:"i"` on the `an_int_variable` first.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `{{ value|slugify }}` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/).

Answer (score 4):

just create a new template tag

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def to_str(value):
    """converts int to string"""
    return str(value)
```

and then go to your template and add in the top of the file

```
{% load to_str %}

{ number_variable|to_str  %}
```