# Django HTML Select not loading correct option

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

Im having some trouble at my first Django project.
I have a ListView in which I have several comboboxes (select) to filter data in a table.
Im using Foundation for my site
The problem I´m having is that once I establish the "filters" for the queary in my comboboxes, data is presenting fine, but after loading the table, one of the selects is not loading the correct option(last lookup)

This is my ListView code:

```
class ListSales(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "sales/list.html"
    context_object_name = 'sales'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login')
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        client = self.request.GET.get("clientselect", "")
        payment_method = self.request.GET.get("paymentselect", "")
        date1 = self.request.GET.get("date1", '')
        date2 = self.request.GET.get("date2", '')
        product = self.request.GET.get("productselect", '')

        if date1 == '':
            date1 = datetime.date.today()
        if date2 == '':
            date2 = datetime.date.today()
        queryset = Sale.objects.get_sales_list(
            date1, date2, client, payment_method)


        qty_total_product = 0
        if product != '0' and product != '':

            print(Product.objects.get(id=product).full_name)
            print(queryset)
            for querysale in queryset:
                print(querysale)
                for query_sale_detail in querysale.sale_details():
                    print(query_sale_detail.product.full_name +
                          "  " + str(query_sale_detail.count))
                    if str(query_sale_detail.product.id) == product:
                        qty_total_product += query_sale_detail.count

        print(qty_total_product)
        obj_sales_list_filter, created_obj_sales_list_filter = SalesListFilters.objects.get_or_create(
            id=1,
            defaults={
                'datefrom': date1,
                'dateTo': date2,
                'client': Client.objects.search_id(client),
                'payment_method': PaymentMethod.objects.search_id(payment_method)
            })
        if not created_obj_sales_list_filter:
            obj_sales_list_filter.datefrom = date1
            obj_sales_list_filter.dateTo = date2
            obj_sales_list_filter.client = Client.objects.search_id(client)
            obj_sales_list_filter.payment_method = PaymentMethod.objects.search_id(
                payment_method)
            obj_sales_list_filter.save()

        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context["clients"] = Client.objects.all().order_by('full_name')
        context["payment_methods"] = PaymentMethod.objects.all()
        context["products"] = Product.objects.all().order_by('full_name')
        sales_list_filters = SalesListFilters.objects.all()
        if sales_list_filters is None or sales_list_filters == {} or not sales_list_filters:
            context["date1"] = str(datetime.date.today())
            context["date2"] = str(datetime.date.today())
        else:
            sales_list_filters = SalesListFilters.objects.get(id=1)
            context["date1"] = str(sales_list_filters.datefrom)
            context["date2"] = str(sales_list_filters.dateTo)
            if(sales_list_filters.client is None):
                context["clientselect"] = 0
            else:
                context["clientselect"] = sales_list_filters.client.id

            if(sales_list_filters.payment_method is None):
                context["paymentselect"] = 0
            else:
                context["paymentselect"] = sales_list_filters.payment_method.id

        current_sale_info = CurrentSaleInfo.objects.get(id=1)
        if current_sale_info is None or current_sale_info == {} or current_sale_info.invoice_number is None:
            context["current_sale_info"] = False
        else:
            context["current_sale_info"] = True

        product = self.request.GET.get("productselect", '')
        print("el producto seleccionado es:"+product+"  "+str(type(product)))
        if(product == '' or product == '0'):
            print("Entro por defecto")
            context["product_select"] = 0
        else:
            print("Entro por valor")
            context["product_select"] = int(product)


        return context
```

I can see in the **kwargs that the variable established fot productselect is loading fine. However, when I set context["product_select"] variable, the html always load option 0.

This is my html:

```
{% extends "panel.html" %}

{% load  static %}

{% block panel-content %}

<div class="grid-x medium-10">
    <h3 class="cell medium-12" style="text-align: center;">Ventas</h3> 
    <div class="cell medium-12">&nbsp </div>
    <form class="cell medium-12" method="GET">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="input-group grid-x medium-12">
            
            <div class="input-group cell medium-2 grid-x">
                <label class="cell medium-12">Desde:</label>
                <span class="input-group-label"><i class="fi-calendar"></i></span>
                <input type="date" id="date1" name="date1" class="input-group-field" type="date" value={{date1}}>
                
            </div>
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <div class="input-group cell medium-2 grid-x">
                <label class="cell medium-12">Hasta:</label>
                <span class="input-group-label"><i class="fi-calendar"></i></span>
                <input type="date" id="date2" name="date2" class="input-group-field" type="date" value={{date2}}>
                
            </div>
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <div class="input-group cell medium-2 grid-x">
                <label class="cell medium-12">Cliente:</label>
                <span class="input-group-label"><i class="fi-torso"></i></span>
                <select id="clientselect" name="clientselect" class="input-group-field">
                    <option value="0" id="option0" name="option0" {% if clientselect is 0 %} selected {% endif %}>Todos</option>
                    <option value="-1" id="option-1" name="option-1" {% if clientselect is -1 %} selected {% endif %}>Sin Cliente</option>
                    {% for client in clients %}
                    <option value="{{client.pk}}" id="option{{client.pk}} "  name="option{{client.pk}}" {% if clientselect is client.pk %} selected {% endif %}>{{client.full_name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                
            </div>

            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <div class="input-group cell medium-2 grid-x">
                <label class="cell medium-12">Método de Pago:</label>
                <span class="input-group-label"><i class="fi-dollar-bill"></i></span>
                <select id="paymentselect" name="paymentselect" class="input-group-field">
                    <option value="0" id="option0" name="option0" {% if paymentselect is 0 %} selected {% endif %}>Todos</option>
                    {% for pm in payment_methods %}
                    <option value="{{pm.pk}}" id="option{{pm.pk}} "  name="option{{pm.pk}}" {% if paymentselect is pm.pk %} selected {% endif %}>{{pm.full_name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                
            </div>

            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <div class="input-group cell medium-3 grid-x">
                <label class="cell medium-12">Producto:</label>
                <span class="input-group-label"><i class="fi-list"></i></span>
                <select id="productselect" name="productselect" class="input-group-field">
                    <option value="0" id="option0" name="option0" {% if product_select is 0 %} selected {% endif %}>Todos</option>
                    {% for prod in products %}
                    <option value="{{prod.pk}}" id="option{{prod.pk}} "  name="option{{prod.pk}}" {% if product_select is prod.pk %} selected {% endif %}>{{prod.full_name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                
            </div>

 
            <div class="cell medium-1">
                <button type="submit" class="button cell medium-4"><i class="fi-filter"></i>&nbsp Filtrar</button>
            </div>


            <div class="cell medium-1">
                <h5>{{product_text}}</h5>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="cell medium-12"> </div>
    <table class="cell medium-12">
        <thead>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Nro Factura</th>
            <th>Cliente</a></th>
            <th>Método de Pago</a></th>            
            <th>Monto</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
         
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for sale in sales %}
            <tr>
                
              <td>{{ sale.show_date }}</td>
              <td>{{ sale.invoice_number }}</td>
              <td>{{ sale.client.full_name }}</td>
              <td>{{ sale.payment_method }}</td>
              <td>${{ sale.amount_with_discount}}</td>
              <td>
              <div class="button-group">
                <a href="#" class="button warning tiny" data-toggle="modalView{{sale.pk}}"><i class="fi-eye"></i></a>
                
            </td>
              </div>

            </tr>

        
            <div class="tiny reveal" id="modalView{{sale.pk}}" style="background-color:rgb(51,51,51);" data-reveal data-close-on-click="true" data-animation-in="spin-in" data-animation-out="spin-out">
                <h4 class="cell" style="text-align: center;">Detalle de Venta</h4>
                <br>
                {% for sale_detail in sale.sale_details %}
                    <h5 style="text-align: center;">{{sale_detail.product.full_name}} X {{sale_detail.count}} : $ {{sale_detail.sale_detail_total}}</h5>
                {% endfor %}
                <h5 style="text-align: center;">--------------------------------------------------</h5>
                <h5 style="text-align: center;">SUB TOTAL: $ {{sale.amount}}</h5>
                <h5 style="text-align: center;">DESCUENTO: $ {{sale.discount}}</h5>
                <h4 style="text-align: center;" class="detailtag">TOTAL: $ {{sale.amount_with_discount}}</h5>
                <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button> 
    
                
            </div>


          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>    

    {% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination cell medium-12">
      {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}&{{ view.urlencode_filter }}" style="color: wheat;">&laquo;</a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span style="color: wheat;">&laquo;</span></li>
      {% endif %} {% for i in paginator.page_range %} {% if page_obj.number == i %}
      <li class="active">
        <span style="color: wheat;">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(actual)</span></span>
      </li>
      {% else %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ i }}&{{ view.urlencode_filter }}" style="color: wheat;">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&{{ view.urlencode_filter }}" style="color: wheat;">&raquo;</a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span style="color: wheat;">&raquo;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}

  </div>

  
  
  {% endblock panel-content %}
```

This is a picture showing that is loading every select, but no the one for products. It´s always loading product "Todos" that is first option:

[image: Before filter]

[image: After filter]

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is `product_select` a string? just in case do this `int(str(product))`.

Comment: @Memristor is working!! I really don´t understad, I tried printing var type begore assigning it and it said <class 'str'>. But it´s working. If you want please post answer and I will put it as correct one. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Memristor Also important, in addition to this I had to use == instead of "is" in html to compare vars

Comment: I think just doing `==` should work. Are you trying to select a pk > 256?

Comment: @aaron hi, thanks for help, i have tried == and it dindnt work

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by OP, I post my answer here:

`product_select` may not be a string, so just in case do it is recommended to do `int(str(product))`.

Comment: Any ideas why if I print variable class and it says its str class, I have to do this you are saying in order dor this to work? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: My guess, because it happened me years ago, is that it depend on each request. Check multiple request and you may find one that is different, not a string. There is also the fact that Django change some of the requests to a dict like depending on some conditions (but as I said I read about it years ago).

Answer (score 1):

Believe the issue is with the `is` in your code:

```
<option value="{{prod.pk}}" id="option{{prod.pk}} "  name="option{{prod.pk}}" {% if product_select is prod.pk %} selected {% endif %}>{{prod.full_name}}</option>
```

Could you please try using `==` along with stringformat filter?

```
<option value="{{prod.pk}}" id="option{{prod.pk}}" name="option{{prod.pk}}" {% if product_select|stringformat:"i" == prod.pk|stringformat:"i" %} selected {% endif %}>{{prod.full_name}}</option>
```

I found this from [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27771117/2679662), actually.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I tried this option but still not working :(